# Ruby on Rails: Convert attribute name inside query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to convert type of created_at inside query

```
 passenger = Passenger.where("created_at.to_date = ?", Date.yesterday)
```

The .to_date method is not working. Can it be done? Is there a workaround for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
passenger = Passenger.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.yesterday)
```

Comment: What about other datatypes? Like string, integer? Just write that in CAPS?

Comment: Depends on the DB.  [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html), [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score -1):

The proper solution will be is:

```
 passengers = Passenger.where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", Date.yesterday)
```

But if you need take only one, you can use

```
passenger = Passenger.find_by(created_at: Date.yesterday)
```

I wrote it because name of variable was not plural

Comment: If you work with dates you should always use `= DATE(?)` in left side and in right side! Code style